# Assigning typedefined array to another one (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays

I am a beginner to programming. My current university assignment tells me to read a text from a file and only get "valid" words, *ie* `end` instead of `end.`.   I got stuck at the part where I have to put a new detected word into an array of words.

Compiler error is: *array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer*

```
int const MAX_WORDS = 100000;
int const MAX_WORDLENGTH = 80;
typedef char Word [MAX_WORDLENGTH];
typedef Word Words [MAX_WORDS];
Words words ;

bool read_file (char filename [80])
{
    ifstream file(filename);
    if(!file) {
        cout << "wrong filename";
        return false;
    }
    char c;
    int word_idx = 0;
    Word word = words[word_idx++];
    int letter_idx = 0;
    int connector_count = 0;
    while (file.get(c)) {
     if ((c>='A' && c<='Z')||(c>='a' && c<='z'))
     {
         word[letter_idx++] = c;
         cout << c << endl;
     }
     else {
        if (c == '-') {
            if(connector_count==0) {
                word[letter_idx++] = c;
                connector_count++;
            }
            else {
                if(connector_count==1) {
                    word[letter_idx-1] ='\n';
                    Word word = words[word_idx++];


                }
            }
        }
     }
    }
```

Comment: And `words` is.... ? For that matter `Word` is... ? (I'm assuming a typedef to a `char` array on the last one). *Edit:* Well look at that, the crystal ball still has some luster.

Comment: sorry forgot the typedef lines...they are now edited!

Comment: I'm going to assume some academic has told you using `std::string` is off the table, because it would make this *significantly* easier.

Comment: actually i haven't been told that.

Comment: @user2966724: does the compiler tell you which line causes the problem? also, in the very last `if` statement in the code you've posted, you append the endline character `\n` to `word` and then reinitialize it again and give it the value of `words[word_idx++]`. i'm not sure you want to do this?

Comment: @stellarossa: i was intending to get a "new word" to work with. And the error i get in line where first appearance of "Word word = words[word_idx++];" is.

Answer (score 0):

this is the line that causes the error (you have two of these):

> Word word = words[word_idx++];

array initialization by assignment is illegal in C++, so for instance if you have something like this:

```
typedef char string[5];
string str = "hello";
```

and you try doing something like this:

`string str2 = str;`

you'll get the same error that you got. the way you deal with this, is by including

`#include <string.h>` and doing this:

`memcpy(str2, str, sizeof(string));`

so in your case, instead of `Word word = words[word_idx++];`, you should do this:

```
Word word;  //declare variable
memcpy(word, words[word_idx++], sizeof(Word)); //copy to variable
```

of course, if you want to avoid future headaches, use `std::string`.

hope this helps.

Comment: @Julius361 no worries! also, take a look at the re-declaring and initializing of `word` in the last `if` block i mentioned in the other comment, it might cause a problem.